# What is an environment where exists all objects from all files sourced when running Shiny App?

Tags: r, shiny

When Shiny App starts, by default it sources e.g. all files with `.R` extension in `R/` as well as `app.R` file or `server.R` and `ui.R` file. I imagine all objects from these files (functions mostly) lives in one common environment. How to get access to this environment? Let's say, I would like to list all objects in this environement in some `renderPrint` output. I have tried:

```
output$env <- renderPrint({
    names(rlang::global_env())
  })
```

But it doesn't work, it founds only `".Random.seed"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html):

> all R code in a Shiny app is run in the global environment or a child of it

I think "*or a child*" is key here.

When you run a Shiny session that happens in an environment - let's call it `A`. All functions from `R/` are stored in another environment - let's call it `B`. Now, both `A` and `B` are (grand)childs of the global environment, but `B` is also a (grand)parent of `A`.

A bit simplified we have something like this:

```
+-- Global environment
|   \-- B (where your functions live)
|       \-- A (current environment)
```

This is why you can access the functions from your app, but you cannot find the functions either in the global environment nor in the current environment of your app.

#### Example

Create a new folder for a Shiny application, and store the following function in `R/whatever.R`:

```r
test_function <- function() print("TEST")
```

Now, in your application, do something like:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    mainPanel(
        verbatimTextOutput("objects")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    test_function()
    
    output$objects <- renderPrint({
        
        x <- pryr::parenvs(rlang::current_env())
        
        for (i in seq_len(length(pryr::parenvs(rlang::current_env())))) {
            
            print(x[[i]])
            print(names(x[[i]]))
            print("-----------------------------")
            
        }
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This should print all environments and their content, starting from your current environment and ending with the global environment. `test_function` will be stored somewhere in between these environments.

To access the environment with your functions, write some logic to find that environment, and access everything there.

---

PS: If you want any object or function to be available in the global environment, you can create them in the file `global.R`. This will run once when the app is started, and should make everything available in the global environment. Read more about it [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html).

Comment: Thank you. Let me also kindly note you about my other question: [How to change object from any environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70495338/how-to-change-object-from-any-environment)